# Bottom AlertDialouge android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a view which i want to show bottom of the MainLayout. When i set the theme as AlertDialouge it always show center of the screen.
is it possible to make it's position manually?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I have already got the answer. @mibac .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Window window = yourDialogReference.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams windowLayoutParams = window.getAttributes();

windowLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
window.setAttributes(windowLayoutParams);
```